# Redoing the factory calibration of LCD panels?

Tags: lcd, display, oled

Is it possible to rewrite factory calibration of LCD panels? I am not talking about buying a Spyder 4 or X-Rite calibration device and generating a software lookup table at the OS, or graphics card levels but the actual internal calibration of the panel so I could say make the intensity response follow some curve other then a standard gamma curve. Do any LCD panel manufactures do custom calibrations on small orders (300 < X < 1000)? I know high end graphics monitors like those from Ezio, and NEC allow for custom intensity response curves but I am looking to use more of a tablet size high res LCD panel.

Comment: ...if your going to down vote me I would appreciate a comment as to why so I don't make the same mistake down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most LCD screens there is no calibration at all. As the background LED is manufactured by a one manufacturer, the LCD manufacturer (just the LED panel without back-light) is generated by another. Since the LCD manufacturer doesn't know which LEDs are going to be used, pre-calibration is impossible.
If you need exact colors it would be a good idea to purchase a panel with a built in driver that has some sort of color correction mechanism or you will have to write one yourself on the MCU/CPU side.

Even if you do find an LCD panel that has a built in driver that support calibration (3x4 matrix, 2D functions or even a 3D LUT engine) you should generate the calibration data with a colorimator (like x-rite or spyder). Doing this by the naked eye is quite hard (impossible??)

And one last thing, if it is a tablet you are after, both Android & iOS has color calibration support and they can be calibrated using a colorimator.